# Tastypie Master entrypoint to several endpoints

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Is it possible to create a Non-Model based Resource that returns entry points for other API endpoints? Consider the following Model Manager from django-postman

https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/src/95d5e1b67a3e643d0a699eba601e779b307d43f9/postman/models.py?at=default#cl-86

I am looking to create an return object like this:

```
{
  "meta": {
  "limit": 20,
  "next": null,
  "offset": 0,
  "previous": null,
  "total_count": 0
  },
  objects:[{
    "inbox":"/api/v1/inbox/",
    "trash":"/api/v1/trash/"
  }]
 }
```

Comment: are inbox and trash related somehow in your example?